# IEnumerable.Select repeats input parameter in a function call

Tags: c#, linq, select

I stumbled upon a behaviour that I would not expect and can't find the documentation of. I have a function with 2 parameters, one of them has a default value. When the function is called inside of a Select, it for some reason takes the value it is called on and applies it for both parameters. Example:

Have the function:

```
private static Directions PrintDir(Directions dir, int distance = 1) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Direction {dir}, distance {distance}");
    return dir;
}
```

If called on its own, it behaves as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    enum Directions { Left, Up, Right, Down };
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintDir(Directions.Left);
        PrintDir(Directions.Up);
        PrintDir(Directions.Right);
        PrintDir(Directions.Down);
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Direction Left, distance 1
Direction Up, distance 1
Direction Right, distance 1
Direction Down, distance 1
```

however when called inside of LINQ expression:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    enum Directions { Left, Up, Right, Down };
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dirs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Directions))
            .Cast<Directions>()
            .Select(PrintDir)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Direction Left, distance 0
Direction Up, distance 1
Direction Right, distance 2
Direction Down, distance 3
```

So it appears the Directions value has been applied correctly as the `dir` parameter, but also converted to int and applied instead of the default value as the second `distance` parameter.

Why does this happen? What are the rules for functions inside Select?

Comment: I expect you're using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__).

Comment: As an aside, do not do `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Directions)).Cast<Directions>()` -- that boxes and then unboxes each individual enum member. Use `Enum.GetValues<Directions>()` if you can, otherwise use `(Directions[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Directions))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [overload of `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) which also contains the index. If you used lambdas, your code would look like this:

```
Select((item,index) => PrintDir(item, index))
```

If you want to avoid it, call your `Select` like this:

```
Select(item => PrintDir(item))
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense, I misinterpreted the behaviour there then. 

Take home message is then that if I want to use functions with default parameter I have to do an explicit lambda call.

Comment: Only if the second default parameter is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little more to SomeBody's answer: if you write `PrintDir(Directions.Left)`, the compiler compiles the code `PrintDir(Directions.Left, 1)` -- it takes the default value and inserts it into the method call for you.

Now, if you try to create a delegate directly from the method, e.g:

```
var f = new Func<Directions, Directions>(PrintDir)
```

there's nowhere for the compiler to insert this default value, so this won't compile. The only delegate type you can assign the method to directly is one which takes all parameters, e.g. `Func<Directions, int, Directions>`.

However, if you write:

```
var f = new Func<Directions, Directions>(x => PrintDir(x))
```

The compiler can turn this into:

```
var f = new Func<Directions, Directions>(x => PrintDir(x, 1))
```

When you write:

```
.Select(PrintDir)
```

you're actully writing shorthand for:

```
.Select(new SomeDelegateType(PrintDir))
```

where `SomeDelegateType` is a suitable delegate type. The compiler searches through all of the overloads of `Select` looking for one which accepts a delegate type which will compile.

There's an overload of `Select` which accepts a `Func<Direction, Direction>`, so it tries this:

```
.Select(new Func<Direction, Direction>(PrintDir))
```

... but that doesn't compile, so it tries the overload which takes the `int` index:

```
.Select(new Func<Direction, int, Direction>(PrintDir))
```

and that *does* compile, so the compiler chooses it.

(In fact things are slightly more complex, as the compiler is inferring the return type (I assumed it's `Direction` above), and it also tries to find the *best* match, but that's the gist of it.)